# How to use Quicktabs as attachment to Views

Tags: views, blocks

Good day,
I made block with 3 tabs using Quicktabs.
Is it possible to use it like attachment to Views page?

I want use contextual filters in Views and do filtering in tabs also....

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but if you make blocks in Views, you can then use them for your Quicktabs

Comment: Yes you are right, also I can use pages for quicktabs. But I want to attach my tabs to a View. I mean, that I have already prepared tabs with Views (blocks) and now want to return them to View.

Comment: Is it possible to use new format Quicktabs which is begin to be avalaible in Forma menu?